# is there a way to virtualize IOT devices on virtual machines

Tags: web-services, api, openstack, virtualization, iot

Is it possible to install a virtual machine on the openstack cloud? Let's say I want to simulate a gps device inside of a virtual machine, I looked a little bit and i found out that i can do it using the command "gpsfake" ( at least this is start but i'm not sure that is really what i'm looking for), i want another iot device virtualized in another virtual machine to constantly get the coordinates from the first VM and then I'll program it to do an action of my choosing later on depending on the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to do it the other way round because openstack is really a cloud os that you might install on a virtual machine and not the other way round.

Basically the shortest routes are :

1) Install virtualbox on your laptop

2) create a virtual machine (ubuntu or centos)

2) install openstack on the virtual machine .Follow either route depending on your choice of VM OS
  A) for centos https://www.rdoproject.org/install/quickstart/
  B) for ubuntu https://docs.openstack.org/developer/devstack/

3) create  instances inside the openstack ( actually virtual machines)

4) Deploy your app inside the instances

Comment: thank you for answering,
yes i already done that, and that's what i mean ...
now that i have installed openstack on 3 nodes, i want to deploy 2 or 3 instances, i want these instances to be a virtualized iot devices like a virtualised gps or something like that. and that's my question, can i deploy virtualized iot devices ?